# How to get a final report in years in for statement

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for p in range(running_weeks):

    #Increase weeks in output
    output_weeks = output_weeks + 1

    #For backend to reset the total
    function_total = function_total + income

    #Real total shown in output
    true_total = true_total + income
    print("Week", output_weeks, "Income", income, "Total", true_total)

    #For every 3000 in total the income increases and the functional total goes to 0
    if math.floor(function_total / money_needed_for_increase) == 1:
        income = income + increase_income
        function_total = 0;
        print("\nIncome increased by: ", increase_income, "\n")

    #Every 52 weeks this message pops
    if output_weeks % 52 == 0: 
        print("\nYear ", output_weeks / 52, "Done Results: Income:", income, "Total", true_total,"\n")
```

With this for statement I'm able to see what happens each week and how much my income will increase and when the year is over. But, I would like to add something so that when the for statement is over, it shows a result of how much I made each year.

Ex:

```
Year 1.0 Income: 10,000 Total: 100,000 
Year 2.0 Income: 11,000 Total: 500,000
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to split `running_weeks` into full years. You can simple use a for loop for that. Here's the example:

```py
years = []
for i in range(0, len(running_weeks), 52):
    years.append(running_weeks[i : i + 52])
```

It will split `running_weeks` into few pieces of size 52. Then you can easily calculate all data about each year.

Answer (score 0):

Try tracking years as a list of sublists, then iterate through the years at the end.  So before your code, add the years list:

```
years = []
for p in range(running_weeks):
```

And as you total each year, append to years:

```
    #Every 52 weeks this message pops
    if output_weeks % 52 == 0:
        print("\nYear ", output_weeks / 52, "Done Results: Income:", income, "Total", true_total,"\n")
        years.append[[income, true_total]]
```

Then at the end, iterate through the years.  Indexes start at 0 and you want year 0 to be treated as 1, so use i+1:

```
for i in range(len(years)):
    year_income, year_total = years[i]
    print('Year', i+1, 'Income:', year_income, 'Total:', year_total)
```